# VS 2017 Error List window Message

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am getting below message in "Error List" window of c#.net core project in vs 2017. Note that I have not added fxcop or stylecop nuget package in the project.

```
Severity    Code    Description 
Message RECS0053    Replace with single call to 'FirstOrDefault()'
```

But some of the other team member not getting the same message on their machine.

I would like to know what tool in vs 2017 makes this message and shows in the error list window.

Note : Even in my machine this message listed only after opening the .cs file containing this code issue.

Comment: Looks like the errorcode `RECS0053` is a part of the following refactor library: **RefactoringEssentials** https://github.com/icsharpcode/RefactoringEssentials/blob/master/RefactoringEssentials/CSharp/Diagnostics/CSharpDiagnosticIDs.cs
Take a look and see if you have it installed.

Comment: Yes , you are correct. I have installed Refactoring Essentials for Visual Studio 2017 extension. Thank you so much.